# Using File Download Control with Java Bean in XPages

Tags: xpages

I would like to use the standard XPages xp:fileDownload control and bind it to a Java Bean rather than a document source.

I have an RTF field in my form - 'resourceAttachments' - along with several other fields in which in which I will be storing several attachments and nothing else.

Can anyone provide me with an example or point me to some documentation. I have a similar requirement for the xp:uploadControl, I can find samples which create a new document, but I am struggling to implement adding and saving to existing documents, I guess I should post another question for that though, but as the two go together I thought I would at least mention it here.

Many thanks.

Mark

```
public class TrainingModule implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6998234266563204541L;
private String description;
private ????  resourceAttachments;  --something here ??
private String unid;

public TrainingModule() {
    String documentId = ExtLibUtil.readParameter(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "key");
    if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(documentId)) {
        load(documentId);
    }
}

public String getUnid() {return unid;}
public void setUnid(final String unid) {this.unid = unid;}

public String getDescription() {return description;}
public void setDescription(final String description) {this.description = description;}

? Some attachment Getter & Setter here??

public void load(final String unid) {setUnid(unid);{
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentDatabase().getDocumentByUNID(getUnid());
        setDescription(doc.getItemValueString("Description"));
    ??Some load here here??


    } catch (Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            doc.recycle();
                        ?some other recycle here?
        } catch (Exception ) {
            // Fail Silent
        }
    }
```

In my Custom Control amongst other things I have...

```
 <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(param.containsKey("key"))  
 {viewScope.put("docAttach",(param.get("key")));}}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
.......
 <xp:fileDownload rows="30" id="fileDownload2" displayLastModified="false" 
value="#{TrainingModule.ResourceAttachments}" hideWhen="true" allowDelete="true">
                </xp:fileDownload>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have dealt a similar problem last year. I haven't looked for an appropriate binding for fileUpload. Instead, I used a different approach.

When you submit an XPage with a file upload, it will upload the file to the disk (regardless of any binding) and create an `com.ibm.xsp.http.UploadedFile` object in the `requestMap`. So you can grab it from a bean method and do the magic.

This is the IBM Connect 2014 demo and I have used this technique to upload file into the BaseCamp.

XSP code is simple ([here is the Github repo](https://github.com/sbasegmez/ic14demos/blob/master/demo1-XPages/odp-ic14xpages/XPages/wAddfile.xsp#L94))

```
<xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload1"></xp:fileUpload>

<xp:button id="button1"
    value="Upload Local File">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
        submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:executeScript
                script="#{bcs.uploadLocalFile}">
            </xp:executeScript>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

`bcs` is the managed bean and here is the code snippet for upload ([from Github repo](https://github.com/sbasegmez/ic14demos/blob/master/demo1-XPages/odp-ic14xpages/Code/Java/com/developi/ic14/xsp/BaseCampService.java#L380))

```
public void uploadLocalFile() {

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();

    String fileUploadID = ExtLibUtil.getClientId(facesContext, facesContext.getViewRoot(), "fileUpload1", false);

    UploadedFile uploadedFile = ((UploadedFile) request.getParameterMap().get(fileUploadID));

    if (uploadedFile == null) {
        facesContext.addMessage("messages1", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "No file uploaded. Use the file upload button to upload a file.", ""));
        return;
    }

    java.io.File file = uploadedFile.getServerFile();
    String contentType=uploadedFile.getContentType();
    String fileName = uploadedFile.getClientFileName();

    // removed unrelated code...

}
```

So, basically, you get the `requestMap`. The `UploadedFile` object refers to a file object that has been uploaded to a temporary area on the server and it's mapped with the `clientId` of the `fileUpload` component.

After this point, you might create a stream and attach the file into a field. When you bind it to a field, document wrapper does the same thing, I guess.

Comment: Many thanks, it might take me a little while to get my head round that, a lot of it is beyond my knowledge at this stage, but thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly the same thing .Serdar - do you mind expanding on your last sentence? If you have a viewScope bean which you only want to save to a doc if the user clicks save, where do you hold the file? If you create a stream to read the file do you then hold it as a field on the bean? if so what type?java.io.File? If you do that then the viewScope bean could get really big in memory. Is there a way to keep it on disk somehow?

Comment: maybe answering my own question here but i think i'd need to..
1) get the uploaded file
2) rename it so it isn't cleared by the server
3) store the path to the new file in my bean as a string
4) add code to the save method of the bean to grab the file and attach it to the doc then delete the source file
5) worry about tidying up uploaded files which are never saved to a doc and clog up the server.  perhaps a clean up in the bean's finalise method?

Comment: Martin, no need to worry about the file. The file will be held until application (or session) timed out. As long as you dance around the view scope, you might save it whenever you want to save. That's how normal upload works, it persists the uploaded file in the `xsppers` folder. So you can keep the OS path of the temporary file inside your bean and attach it whenever you need.